# Object.defineProperty recursion in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am creating a custom object property for the Element.prototype using this:

```
if (Object.defineProperty) {
    Object.defineProperty(window.Element.prototype, myPropName, {
        get: function() {
            var tmpProp = new myProp(this);
            Object.defineProperty(this, myPropName, {
                get: function () {
                    tmpProp._refresh();
                    return tmpProp; 
                },
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
            return tmpProp;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
}
```

My goal is to create the new property object the first time it is accessed and on subsequent accesses, call the _refresh method before returning the object.  This works for Chrome & Firefox.  But with Internet Explorer it causes an infinite recursion loop.  I have tested with IE8, IE9 and IE11 and it happens in all those versions.

It seems that when the inner Object.defineProperty is executed, it automatically calls the original property accessor.  I am guessing that when I define a new property on a object that has a same name property in its prototype chain, it immediately calls that prototype accessor.

Is this a known bug/difference in how IE handles Object.defineProperty?  If so, what is the fix or workaround?  I have tried using "delete this[myPropName]" but that doesn't seem to work.  I can only guess it is because it deletes the property from the object instance and not from the prototype chain?

There is a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ky4g73mg/2/) that has some added console logging for demonstration.  And if there is a better way to achieve my goal, please let me know.  This is a learning experience for me.

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: Oh, so this is because DOM objects in internet explorer have different behavior from regular objects?  I didn't even think to check that.  But my example was a simplified version.  I am really attempting to improve the performance of a classList shim I found on github and I thought "patching" the Element prototype was an accepted way of doing this? Is there any way to fix or workaround this defineProperty behavior for DOM objects besides creating the property each time it is accessed?

Comment: Yes, that's quite possible. IE was also known for only supporting getters/setters on DOM objects at all, it definitely didn't follow the standard model everywhere.

Comment: Yes, doing this to shim `.classList` is fine, you might have stated in your question what you wanted to do. I guess you can a) use a flag for checking and avoiding recursion b) just leave the getter and cache the object in a `.__classList` property

Comment: Thanks for your help.  And sorry about not being clear about what I was trying to do.  I did find another workaround by removing the getter from the Element prototype, creating the property for the instance and then restoring the getter to the Element prototype.  That page for the link you gave me says that using Object.defineProperty can cause a reflow in some versions of IE so caching the object might give better peformance.

Comment: I can hardly believe that removing and restoring the getter on the prototype will improve performance, but feel free to benchmark and share your results.